# Uploading a .zip file as binary InputStream from REST service

Tags: java, rest, zip, wildfly, resteasy

I have developed a REST Service with RESTEasy 3.0.12 deployed on WildFly 9 to upload a file in local file system.
I was trying to upload a zip file (testing with POST MAN sending file as binary not multi-part) I could successfully upload CSV, TXT, file format but when I try to send a ZIP file it saves correctly in the local file system but when I try to unzip it says

- Headers error
- Unconfirmed start of archive
- Warnings: headers error
- There are some data after the end of the payload data

**Code:**

```
@Path("/uploadZip")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadZip(@Context HttpServletRequest req, InputStream payload){

    // save to filesystem local.

    Writer wr = null;
    String tempFileName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        try {
            wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFileName));
            IOUtils.copy(payload, wr, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return errorResponse;
        } finally {
            // closing writer and stream
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(wr);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(payload);
        }

        ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to save a good zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***General information on your Headers error:

Zip files contain local headers and a central directory at the end of the file. I don't know the gruesome details--and I won't attempt to expand upon them, but if you're getting a headers error then your zip file is corrupt. I'm not sure what you mean by there is some data after the "payload data."

***Thoughts on your code: Let's think conceptually.

Your endpoint is capturing an InputStream object, which is the superclass of all InputStream objects that represent an input stream of bytes. Your file is essentially wrapped in an object that you can read from byte-for-byte. The first problem I see is that you declare a Writer to write those bytes from the InputStream. Remember--Readers and Writers are for writing *character streams*, Input and Output streams are for *byte streams*. This explains why your CSV and TXT files are successful. It is important to know that difference and remember it!

```
@Path("/uploadZip")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadZip(@Context HttpServletRequest req, InputStream payload){

OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/filename.zip");

    try {
        byte[] bufferSize = new byte[1024];
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = payload.read(bufferSize)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return errorResponse;
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
    ...
}
```

I am confident that it will work. Let me know if this gives you any trouble. Best of luck!